# JSON content is not returned with https POST request

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

The below code with Rest-assured (2.4.0) I am not getting a `JSON` response.

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;
import com.jayway.restassured.RestAssured;
import com.jayway.restassured.http.ContentType;
import com.jayway.restassured.response.Response;`

String logInPayload = "{}" // take any JSON request string.
RestAssured.baseURI = "https:"; // take any https post url.
JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) jsonParser.parse(logInPayload);
Response resp = RestAssured.given()
        .accept(ContentType.JSON).and()
        .header("Accept", "application/json").and()
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json").and()
        .body(jsonObject.toJSONString()).and()
        .request().relaxedHTTPSValidation().and()
        .when().post(RestAssured.baseURI);

 System.out.println(resp.getBody().asString());
 System.out.println(resp.contentType());
```

Out Put is:

```
<html>
<head><title>401 Authorization Required</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>401 Authorization Required</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.7</center>
</body>
</html>

text/html    //second println statement
```

Instead of above text/`html` I am expecting as `JSON` string.

Expected is:

```
{
  "message": "No such user with this email",
  "code": "10003"
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: The return stream states that authentication failed and your log in payload string is empty.  That probably needs a user ID and password, formatted and delimited in a way that the server expects.

Comment: What type of authentication does the URL you're trying to access require?

Comment: Due to some confidential issues i was not given any payload string and server URL. my main expectation is i want to get the JSON string as my output with https://

Comment: You may have have two levels of authentication. The first is just to submit something to the server. That is failing with a 401.  If you were to get past that then you you might get the expected JSON back indicating the error (i.e. No such user with the given email).

Comment: @ mbmast From the above code is perfectly working with http:// POST URL i am getting a json response as { "message": "No such user with this email", "code": "10003" } for invalid user

Comment: Any one have any solution on this please provide the solution for this thanks in advance

Comment: You appear to be contradicting yourself.  In your question you state you are getting the HTML response but expecting the JSON response.  In your comments you state the code works perfectly and you are getting the JSON response.  Which is it?  And if you are getting the JSON response, then what exactly is the problem you are asking about?

Comment: @ mbmast, Thanks for commenting, The thing is the code is perfectly working in HTTP protocol but the code is not working in HTTPS protocol. But this problem was solved i to don't know how it was solved now the code is perfectly working on both HTTP & HTTPS protocols